# any solution to simulate trigger behaviour on public group membership

Tags: trigger, public-group

It doesn't seem to be supported to have triggers on the GroupMembership object.

**I want to update a field on the user object every time a user becomes part of certain public groups.**

Neither workflows or triggers are possible on the group membership object.

Does anyone have ideas on what could be an alternative solution?

What I'm thinking off too is having a scheduled apex job that runs for example twice a day but I'm not too much in favor of that.

Any thoughts?

Comment: KoenVM - did David's answer help? Could you mark it correct, or leave a comment?

Answer (score 1):

(Separate answer because my first answer, while not answering the question, is true.)

The GroupMember object is [not a triggerable object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_groupmember.htm).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you cannot write trigger on this object.

You can write schedule process, that run every 1 hour, search for new GroupMember and do the update on related users

Answer (score 0):

[You can put triggers on CollaborationGroupMember object](https://developer.salesforce.com/releases/release/Spring13/Triggers+for+CollaborationGroup+and+CollaborationGroupMember) - I don't know why it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: A bit a late reply but the question was related to the GroupMembership object and not the chatter group membership object.